# Why did some of the Death Eaters leave when Harry was revealed to be alive?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), we can see few people of the Voldemort's team leaving him:

[image]

Why did they do this?

Comment: Presumably because a few of them had already been killed in the crossfire

Comment: Voldemort has failed *yet again* to eliminate Potter.  The smarter ones can see the tide turning, and not in their favor.

Comment: Rats fleeing a sinking ship

Comment: @Valorum what crossfire? No spells cast in that gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've rewatched the movie recently, and my understanding was some Death Eaters were abandoning Voldemort after witnessing his failure to kill Harry Potter. Voldemort is a bully ruling by fear alone. Seeing his impotence could change the mind of certain followers.

Comment: And although this may well be the case, can you offer any evidence to back it up?

Comment: I watched the movie? What else do you want? Unless you contact the screenwriter or the director, there isn't much else to go on, is it?

Comment: Well, off the top of my head there was a book, there's access to the original screenplay, umpteen interviews with cast, crew, etc that may prove fruitful. I'm assuming OP already saw the movie and that they were probably looking for a deeper analysis than *what Moohbear thought*.

Comment: Excuse me for thinking then. I'll turn my brain in right away.

Comment: A few books and movies before, when Voldemort returned, he was extremely angry at his Death Eaters for wavering in their devotion.  There's that unmasking scene in the Goblet of Fire. Some Death Eaters, like Belatrix, are true fanatical followers, death or high water. Some are there because of greed and interest (Lucius Malfoy) and some are there only because of fear (Petigrew/Scabbers). I assume that some in the second and third group decided to run away.

Comment: To add to that, the scenes looked very telling. Voldemort returns with the forest with Hagrid carrying Harry's body. He walks to the gate of Hogwarts to show the Order, the staff and the students they're defeated and give them an ultimatum. Neville stands up while some in the background waver. Then Harry shows up, alive. The shots of Voldemort and the Death Eaters in the background show a lot of anxiety and confusion. Some Death Eaters look around the group and at each other and then fly away. It makes it clear that Voldemort has lost the support of a number of his followers at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The trails of black smoke don't necessarily mean the Death Eaters were leaving. Note the similar occurrence at the end of *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*:

In that instance the Death Eaters weren't leaving, they were simply beginning the combat against the Order of the Phoenix. In *Deathly Hallows* as well, this is the moment where combat commences (resumes), so it is not unexpected to see the same thing.